# Irregular result in zombie example

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process, operating-system

I have problems with understanding the behavior of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int nr;
nr = fork();
  if (nr == 0) {
    /* Child process */
    printf("Child process, fork return value %d\n", nr);
    exit(0);
  } else {
    /* Parent process */
    printf("Parent process, fork return value: %d\n", nr);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

When running in a Unix shell I get this result:

```
Parent process, fork return value: 343
Child process, fork return value: 0
```

But sometimes its only giving me this result without any shell prompt:

```
Child process, fork return value: 0
```

I know it can be solved with wait() function in parent process. But I like to know:

Why is result irregular? Could someone please explain what happening? Child process becomes a zombie, but why do not parents process printf() function call run?

Comment: I tried this on Linux and could never observe what you describe.  Instead I always get both messages.  I even tried to put a sleep in the father and/or the child but besides the expected delays, nothing changed.  Also theoretically I cannot find any explanation for your observations.  Would you mind telling us on what system this happens at yours?

Comment: Father process should print the message as well. Zombie process is when child process finishes execution before parent does a `wait` on it. The printf is executed before it becomes a `zombie process`. The parent should print its message regardless of child process... they are seperate processes after fork sharing the same `stdout` as you didn't redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issuse to concider:
1) there is stdout buffering that you might want to flush

```
fflush(stdout);
```

2) multitasking can sometimes execute the stuff in an unexpected order
I get something like this when that happens:

```
/tmp$ ./a.out
Parent process, fork return value: 24049
/tmp$ Child process, fork return value 0
```

as you can see the prompt is in the beginning of the child process output, it's not missing altogether it's just not where you expect it to be.

With this code I tried several times bit never had the prompt in teh output lines of the child or parent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int nr;
nr = fork();
  if (nr == 0) {
    /* Child process */
    printf("Child process, fork return value %d\n", nr);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
  } else {
    /* Parent process */
    printf("Parent process, fork return value: %d\n", nr);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong as it doesn't matter what is the order of execution, both messages should have printed to `stdout`. What OP observed is parent not printing.

Comment: No what the OP is probably observing is out of order printing dew to multi tasking. I've reproduced the error and I can spot the prompt being displayed in one of the output lines.

Comment: If he is missing an entire line I there's a good chance that the fflush will fix that.